# Problem with decryption of AES key with RSA and message decryption

Tags: java, encryption, base64, aes, rsa

I am working on secure chat application. I have AES key for ecrypt/decrypt message and users have own public/private RS keys for encrypt/decrypt AES key. My code give me error like this:

```
> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:383)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:294)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:363)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2164)
    at org.fastchat.User.decryptAESKey(User.java:183)
    at org.fastchat.User.readMessage(User.java:210)
    at org.fastchat.WatchInbox.startWatch(WatchInbox.java:59)
    at org.fastchat.WatchInbox.run(WatchInbox.java:32)
```

Error is in function for decrypting AES key with RSA private key. I found that problem could be with wrong key (keys stored in serialization, every user have once generated keys in profile object) or encode/decode problems. I decide to store encrypted AES key in some file and read that file for decrypt AES key. Is there some better way for store encypted AES key? Am I doing encode/decode in right way? Any help is welcome, I dont have any ideas now. My code is here and every part of proccess is in different function.

```
public SecretKey generateAESkey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    System.out.println("Generating AES key...\n");
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    keyGenerator.init(128, random);
    SecretKey aeSecretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
    System.out.println("AES1 KEY " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(aeSecretKey.getEncoded())));
    System.out.println("===========================\n");
    return aeSecretKey;
    // return keyGenerator.generateKey();
}

public byte[] encryptAESKey(SecretKey key, PublicKey pubKey) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Encrypt AES key...\n");

    String aesKey = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(key.getEncoded()));
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
    byte[] aesEnc = cipher.doFinal(aesKey.getBytes());
    System.out.println("AES ENCRYPTED: " + aesEnc);
    System.out.println("==========================\n");
    return aesEnc;
    // return cipher.doFinal(aesToEnc);
}

public byte[] encryptMessage(String message, SecretKey aeSecretKey) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Encrypt message...\n");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aeSecretKey);
    byte[] msgBytes = message.getBytes(); // This will be encrypted
    byte[] msgEnc = cipher.doFinal(msgBytes);
    System.out.println("=============================\n");
    return msgEnc;
    // return cipher.doFinal(msgBytes); //This will be in .txt file
}

public void checkerUpdate(User receiver) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter check = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(receiver.getCheck() + "/" + getUsername() + ".txt"));
    Random random = new Random();
    Integer num = random.nextInt(100);
    check.write(num);
    check.close();
}

public void sendMessage(String message, User receiver) throws Exception {

    // First generate AES key
    SecretKey aesSecretKey = generateAESkey(); // keysize = 128

    // Encrypt message with AES key, will be in file
    byte[] encMsg = encryptMessage(message, aesSecretKey);

    // Encrypt AES key, put in file
    byte[] aesEnc = encryptAESKey(aesSecretKey, receiver.getPub());

    // Send message and key to receiver
    FileOutputStream msgWrite = new FileOutputStream(receiver.getInbox() + "/" + getUsername() + ".msg", true);
    FileOutputStream keyWrite = new FileOutputStream(receiver.getInbox() + "/" + getUsername() + ".kgn", true);
    keyWrite.write(Base64.getEncoder().encode(aesEnc));
    msgWrite.write(Base64.getEncoder().encode(encMsg));
    keyWrite.close();
    msgWrite.close();

    // Add file to CHECKER, temp operations for WatchInbox service
    checkerUpdate(receiver);
}

// FUNCTIONS FOR DECRYPTION

public byte[] decryptAESKey(byte[] aesEnc) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Decrypt AES key...\n");
    byte[] aesEncString = Base64.getDecoder().decode(aesEnc);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getPriv());
    byte[] decAes = cipher.doFinal(aesEncString);
    System.out.println("===========================\n");
    return decAes;
    // return cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(aesEnc));
}

public String decryptMessage(byte[] msg, SecretKeySpec aeskey) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Decrypt message...\n");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aeskey);
    String msgDec = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(msg)).toString();
    System.out.println("============================\n");
    return msgDec;
    // return cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(msg)).toString();
}

public String readMessage(User sender) throws Exception {
    // Read file in inbox
    File msgtoRead = new File(getInbox() + "/" + sender.getUsername() + ".msg");
    FileInputStream keytoRead = new FileInputStream(getInbox() + "/" + sender.getUsername() + ".kgn");
    // Read 128bits from filetoRead. That is encrypted key.
    byte[] aesEnc = new byte[128];
    keytoRead.read(aesEnc);

    // Decrypted aes key for decode
    byte[] aesDec = decryptAESKey(aesEnc);
    SecretKeySpec aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(aesDec, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

    // Read message
    byte[] message = Files.readAllBytes(msgtoRead.toPath());
    keytoRead.close();

    // Decrypt message with loaded AES key (aesKey), return this
    return new String(decryptMessage(message, aesKey));
}
```

Comment: This is about key management. So you're using the wrong key in all likelihood.  So the missing code for key management is likely to blame and we cannot really help you with that given the code. Note that both AES in CBC mode and RSA in PKCS#1 v1.5 mode are extremely insecure for a chat app.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes  You thing that I must post here code for RSA key generating and RSA key storing? When I register user I give him RSA key pair and store thath with serialization in object. When user login, I load user information like RSA keys, usernames etc

Comment: `String msgDec = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(msg)).toString();` is a bug. `toString()` doesn't do anything useful on arrays. Instead you should create a string with `new String();`. Always specify the Charset UTF-8 when using `new String()` and `String.getBytes()`.

Comment: `byte[] aesEnc = new byte[128];  keytoRead.read(aesEnc);` this is an unreliable method, and only maybe works for 2048 bit keys. Just use `Files.readAllBytes()` like you do a few lines later.

Comment: For some reason you're base64-encoding your AES key before you RSA encrypt it. Please go through your code again and understand every step of it and why you do things like base64 encode some byte arrays and not others.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk Thank you man!